# How do you use ajax Toolkit prefix in web.config with AJAX Toolkit v4? (without assembly)

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Alright, so I deleted AJAX toolkit v1.0 from the GAC even though I had only installed .net framework 4 (you would think .net framework 4 would come with ajax toolkit v4). I deleted it because I thought then I would be able to use gacutil to insert to assembly the v4 AjaxControlToolkit.dll I have.

However, in Windows 7, it's not allowing me to do that.

Now I lost my ajax toolkit install. Though I can reinstall the old version v1, from msi.

And I have a reference in my web.config that is throwing errors:

```
<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.40412.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28F01B0E84B6D53E" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>
```

I need to use the ajaxToolkit tags so I need the tagprefix. But I don't have an assembly, and for hours I tried, and it refuses to add to assembly.

So I have to just include it in the project bin as a dll. Well now it conflicts with the web.config.

What am I suppose to do?

Comment: what errors are being thrown?

Comment: @Pauli it was saying something about not being able to find the assembly, or that it's conflicting with the inclusion of the dll.   "Error 104 Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.40412.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)  
"

Comment: I also reinstalled the ajax toolkit 1.0 msi. So now the v1 reference is back. I just don't understand why they don't give us an MSI for v4, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should be able to leave out the version, culture and public key part. Especially if you just put the AjaxControlToolkit.dll file in the bin-folder you can do with *<add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit"/>* and you don't have to put it in the GAC

Comment: Wow well that fixed a lot of my problems. I thought we had to put versions. Type an answer so I can give you pts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just made a fresh install of AJAX Toolkit from the msi that is provided. Then match the correct version number in the web.config.