# Ajax control toolkit error when added into the project

Tags: ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

**Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "AjaxControlToolkit.Properties.Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AjaxControlToolkit" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.**

This is the error I got when I added Ajax Control Toolkit to my project and added a control in one of my pages and tried to run the app.

Answer (score 5):

This may caused by

1. You missed adding this line to your page.

   ```
   <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
   ```
2. No script manger defined. Add to the asp form run at server

   ```
   <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
   ```
3. If you use a master page add script manger to the master and add

   ```
   <asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManagerProxy>`
   ```

   to the child pages and user controls.
4. Make sure you use the right version of `AjaxControlToolkit` for the control you use.

Comment: `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager> `, this worked

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET make sure you have the following line:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

And always add a `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>` Before using a Extender

Comment: Do I need to register the above line in every page? I added it in the web.config

Comment: I think you have to call it on the webpage, not sure though, I always use it on a single page.

How do you have in it on your web.config?

Comment: <add tagPrefix="Ajax" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787502/how-do-you-use-ajax-toolkit-prefix-in-web-config-with-ajax-toolkit-v4-without